# Can C# target selectors like jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, events, layout

jQuery can select the Child of something, or Parent, or next tag. Does C# have something similar to this behavior. For example, I have a horizontal `StackPanel` that has a `Label`, a TextBox, and a `Button`.

Can I target the `Label` to change color if the `TextBox` is currently selected without using if else statements referring to the name of the `Label`? Some function like "this label" in this `StackPanel` that this `TextBox` is in.

Example: Whenever a text box is selected, the label next to it changes to yellow background.

[image]

I'm not sure how to write this in C# so I will try to explain with regular text.

```
if (this) textbox is selected
    get the label next to it
    change the label background to a color

else
    remove the color if it is not selected
```

The Method() will trigger based on the currently selected `TextBox`.

A function like this can have the same code but be able to target different `Labels` once the focus changes to a different `TextBox`. Is this possible?

Comment: Every control has `Parent` and `Children`, but there is no specific CSS selector like functionality, unless you build it yourself.

Comment: What have you tried?  And can you be a little more clear in what you're trying to do?  Your question is not really clear.

Comment: C#? Surely you don't mean XAML?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to C# behavior. Being able to change the color programmatically.

Comment: C# is a programming language, like JavaScript. It has no ability to "select" anything. Instead, it gives you the ability to _write_ such an ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can; you should handle events. for example in this case you handle 'TextBox.GotFocus` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx).

```
void tb_GotFocus(object sender, GotFocusEventArgs e)
{
     // here you can get the StackPanel as the parent of the textBox and 
     // search for the Lable
     TextBox tb=(TextBox)sender;
     StackPanel sp=tb.Parent as StackPanel;

     // and ...
}
```

If you want to omplete this example let me know.

**Edit**
This is a working Example:

Use this Window to show the results:

```
Window win = new Window();
        StackPanel stack = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        stack.Children.Add(new CustomControl());
        stack.Children.Add(new CustomControl());
        stack.Children.Add(new CustomControl());
        stack.Children.Add(new CustomControl());
        win.Content = stack;
win.ShowDialog();
```

Here, is the CustomControl class:

```
public class CustomControl : Border
{
    Label theLabel = new Label {Content="LableText" };
    TextBox theTextbox = new TextBox {MinWidth=100 };

    public CustomControl()
    {
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel { Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal};
        this.Child = sp;
        sp.Children.Add(theLabel);
        sp.Children.Add(theTextbox);

        theTextbox.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(tb_GotFocus);
        theTextbox.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(tb_LostFocus);
    }


    void tb_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        theLabel.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
    void tb_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        theLabel.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried something like this. But once I have 20 textboxes, I will have to add events to all 20. Can a method be created that changes the `label` color  that is next to the selected `textbox`

Comment: Then, I think the best way is to Create a Custom Control. I 'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp I editted my post. I thought you just want the idea. sorry.

Comment: Thanks Ramin. I have reformatted your code slightly. But I am receiving errors in 3 areas so I can't verify if this works. theTextbox.GotFocus = tb_GF; and GotFocusEventArgs are not working for me

Comment: @MiddleCSharp I editted my post. I thought you just want the idea. Sorry.

Comment: can you please complete the code.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp Yes, see the edit, I checked it and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. This example works.